# Docker, RabbitMQ Receiver gets java.net.ConnectException: Connection Refused

Tags: java, spring, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to containerize a RabbitMQ Sender-Receiver application as part of a larger project. Both the sender and the receiver are Spring applications, and both have the RabbitMQ Container name set as the spring.rabbitmq.hostname. After the sender manages to transmit the data successfully (I transmit a new row of a text file every second), the receiver reads a number of the rows with success. However, after a few of the rows have been read, I get a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection Refused` Exception for each remaining row. What is weird is that for every single one of the faulty rows, I get both the exception and the success message that the data has been received (as for the rows received with succes). Here is the docker-compose.yml file for RabbitMQ:

```
  rabbitmq_service:
    container_name: rabbitmq-container
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbithostname
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: /
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"      
  rabbitreceiver-service:
    container_name: rabbitreceiver-container
    image: rabbitmq-receiver
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_service
  rabbitsender-service:
    container_name: rabbitsender-container
    image: rabbitmq-sender
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_service
```